# Setting up private docker registry with a frontend

Tags: docker, frontend, docker-compose, docker-registry

I am trying to set up a docker registry with a frontend and am having problems
I use the following docker compose, and am unable to see the repos that are present in the registry. I assume the most basic setup as follows:

```
web:
  container_name: registry-frontend
  image: hyper/docker-registry-web
  ports:
    - "8085:8080"
  links:
    - registry
  environment:
   REGISTRY_HOST: registry
registry:
  container_name: registry
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /registry
  volumes:
    - /data/docker-registry/:/registry
```

When I check for repositories present in the registry service, I can see the repos
I ran the following command:

```
http://<host>:5000/v2/_catalog
```

and got the following result

```
{"repositories":["baseimage","myfirstimage"]}
```

However, these are not visible in the frontend. Essentially the integration does not seem to be working. Can anyone help out in figuring out what could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to give "REGISTRY_PORT: 5000" in the environment of your web container as well.